# Is there a way to create new Category Tabs in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-categories

I love the idea of categories.  Kind of like applied filters.

I'd love to create my own custom applied filters as new categories, and be able to list those categories on the front page.

Comment: No, not really. The closest you might be able to come is the Multiple Inboxes Lab which lets your set up a few (three?) different Inboxes based on your criteria (e.g., starred, important, a particular filter, etc.).

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't create categories with Gmail (yet). You could try the multiple inboxes feature, but it feels a bit primitive compared to tabs.

Multiple Inboxes (MI) is a Gmail Labs feature. It requires switching off the standard category tabs (i.e., only one default inbox view). You can then have custom search results listed above/below/beside this main inbox.

You can have up to 5 filters. The results are separated from other results and the main inbox by headers and a bit of whitespace. You can choose how long the filter lists are; default display is top 9 results per filter.

The filtering used by categories is a bit more complex than what most users can cook up for themselves. So if you want to re-create some of the category tabs using the MI feature it may not work as well, and of course the limit of 5 filters is rather restrictive.

Compared to tabs it may involve much more scrolling as there is no way to quickly view the filter results from the navigation bar/label list.
[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

The best workaround I found for not being able to create custom categories is to set a filter that automatically applies a label and archives emails from specific senders. I just scroll to the label whenever I need/want to interact with those specific emails and can easily ignore them when I don't.

Answer (score 0):

I found this as a workable solution

Using labels as categories/folders

Move emails to label/folder
https://www.wikihow.com/Move-Mail-to-Different-Folders-in-Gmail

move all emails from a sender to a folder gmail
https://www.reddit.com/r/GMail/comments/5i4w3n/can_i_automatically_move_emails_from_a_sender_to/